# How can I execute a command with parameters though Kubernetes c# API method "WebSocketNamespacedPodExecAsync"?

Tags: c#, .net, api, kubernetes

From my machine I am able to execute the following command in powershell

```
kubectl --namespace myNameSpace exec myPodName cat myFileName.txt
```

How can I execute the same command thought Kuberneres c#.NET method "***WebSocketNamespacedPodExecAsync***"

Also any reference on how to pass a command with parameters to "***WebSocketNamespacedPodExecAsync***" would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it as follows:

```
WebSocket webSocket = await client.WebSocketNamespacedPodExecAsync(myPodName, myNameSpave, new string[] { "cat", "composer.json" });
```

Reference:
https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp/commit/d20e2597b9f41e8dcf8925bdd383d34d444f9d44